# How to generate dynamic C# images?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, graphics, asp.net-web-api, gdi+

Basically, I want to rehash [VisualCube](http://cube.crider.co.uk/visualcube.php), written previously in PHP.

I've looked into GDI+, tried to find books that dealt with C#, graphics, etc.

Everything somewhat relevant is aimed at only WinForms or WPF, while I'd ideally want to create a WebAPI or WCF service that serves up the images.

What technologies can I use for this? If GDI+, can someone provide me a usage in WebAPI/WCF?

I'd be accessing the WebAPI/WCF through MVC4.

Comment: Why serving images via WCF? you could generate them locally?

Comment: That's definitely an option - how would I go about doing that?
I was hoping long-term that other people would use the WebAPI. I'm really not leaning towards WCF specifically, either local or WebAPI

Comment: Whats the problem using WPF for drawing the cubes?

Comment: I think maybe I had a misunderstanding about WPF? Is it not an alternative to WinForms?

Comment: I probably mis something here, if you want the cubes to be drawn local, you can use WPF. If you want to generate images of cubes via a webpage, you should use something else.

Comment: Basically:
On page load I want to be able to call something like website.net/cubeGenerator?alg=RUR'U' and have an image spit out. What could I use for that? Push your response as an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hanselman has an example with explanation:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx

```
 public ActionResult DynamicImage()
    {
        using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(200, 200))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                string text = "Hello World!";

                Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
                SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                PointF stringPonit = new PointF(0, 0);

                g.DrawString(text, drawFont, drawBrush, stringPonit);
            }

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lovely, thanks! So I should just research the Bitmap and Graphics classes more?

Comment: Yep, also look at Jeroen answer, it is very interesting too, although I never tried that by my own.

Comment: One thing to note: the documentation explicitly says this is not supported. It might work, but there's no guarantee of stability.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5

Answer (score 2):

You could check here: using-wpf-to-generate-a-bitmap

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2857e468-c32a-45dd-be02-cbd920259950/using-wpf-to-generate-a-bitmap-or-other-image-on-an-aspnet-web-application-form